# Trying to align search form to the right of a <li>

Tags: html, css, alignment, searchbar

I am trying to align my search bar to the right side of the li menu items.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="navbox">
        <nav id="nav">
            <ul id="nav">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Leaders</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Youth</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li>
                    <form method="get" action="/search" id="search">
                        <input name="q" type="text" size="40" placeholder="Search..." />
                    </form>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
form {
padding-left: 15px;
margin: 0;
}
```

Is there any way possible to accomplish this?

Comment: I have fixed this problem, but what would I have to do to make this form actually search my site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display:inline-block` will work for you.

```
ul#nav li {
  display:inline-block
}
```

You can find [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f7hy1yur/) here.

Answer (score 1):

yes sure, you can simply add this line to your CSS:

```
nav, ul, li {display:inline-block}
```

and it will work. But a comment: be sure not to use the same ID twice. And try to use classes whenever possible (which is almost always)

Just in case, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kc0zda5n/) so you can play around, try adding paddings, margins, whatever, adn see how it reacts